# How can I convert a hexadecimal value back into a character?

Tags: vb.net

All I need to do is translate two characters from Hexadecimal into text. It's a simple explanation and you will be able to understand more by looking at my code. Does anybody know how to do this one line of code?

```
 Function IndexDecode() As String
        Dim sText As String = "68656c6c6f"
        Dim sDecode As String = ""
        Dim iLength As Integer
        Dim iRemainingLength As Integer = 0
        Dim sAnswer As String = ""
        iLength = Len(sText)

        Do Until iLength = 0
            sDecode = Left(sText, 2)
            'Need code to change the 2 characters into one letter
            sDecode = sDecode + ???
            sAnswer &= sDecode
            iRemainingLength = iLength - 2
            sText = sText.Substring(3, iRemainingLength)
            iLength = Len(sText)
        Loop
        Return sDecode
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
chr(val("&H" + sDecode))
```

The val() function returns the number a string represents, the &H prefix tells it the number is Hex.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code above.

**First** you should return the variable sAnswer, not the transient sDecode.

**Second**, you could simplify a lot your loop without using many temporary variables

**Third** the index to extract substrings should start from zero, so removing the two bytes from the input string should use the index 2

**Finally** you could use the conversion to an integer base 16 to build a char array and then use that char array to create a new string used to build the final one

```
Function IndexDecode() As String
    Dim sText As String = "68656c6c6f"
    Dim sDecode As String = ""
    Dim sAnswer As String = ""

    Do while sText.Length > 0
        sDecode = Left(sText, 2)
        Dim cvt() = new Char() {ChrW(Convert.ToInt32(sDecode, 16))}
        sDecode = new string(cvt)
        sAnswer &= sDecode
        sText = sText.Substring(2)
    Loop
    Return sAnswer
End Function
```